# What Version of Windows Mobile 6.5 is on my Device?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a Symbol MC 75.  It is running Windows Mobile 6.5, but there are several updates after the basic Windows Mobile 6.5:

- Windows Mobile 6.5
- Windows Mobile 6.5.1
- Windows Mobile 6.5.3
- Windows Mobile 6.5.5

How do I know which one I am running?

I went to the about page for my device and it just says Windows Mobile 6.5.  Does that mean I only have the 6.5 or is it not bothering to show me the update version?

NOTE: The CE OS version is: 5.2.21840 (build 21840.5.0.60) in case that helps.

Note 2: The reason I care is that there is a [Developer Tool Kit that is targeted for 6.5.3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c0213f68-2e01-4e5c-a8b2-35e081dcf1ca&displaylang=en) and I want to know if I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like builds 5.2.28xxx are for 6.5.3 and 5.2.21xxx are for 6.5

Sources:

[source 1](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3avyWDW_ruSXIJ%3awww.phonearena.com/htmls/Updated-Windows-Mobile-6.5-to-bring-new-keyboard-more-capacitive-friendly-UI-article-a_8076.html+minimum+build+numbers+for+windows+mobile+6.5.3&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) (and in case the google-cached page doesn't show [here's the original](http://www.phonearena.com/htmls/Updated-Windows-Mobile-6.5-to-bring-new-keyboard-more-capacitive-friendly-UI-article-a_8076.html))

[source 2](http://www.wmexperts.com/windows-mobile-653-28004-out-and-about) (read the comments areas too)

Comment: The version numbers shown in About are AKU level related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation_kit_upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the start button is on the bottom with 6.5.3.  Since it is still on the top corner I am guessing I am on 6.5 or 6.5.1.

Comment: Yes, 6.5.3 is much more finger friendly.  See the images here: http://www.engadget.com/photos/microsoft-windows-mobile-6-5-3-shown-off-very-very-quietly/#2603099

Comment: Alas, my MC 75 does not have that.  I may try to get it though if only for the nicer Soft Input Panel.  (My app hides the OS so most of the OS specific stuff will not matter.)

Answer (score -1):

Tap on Start>Settings>System>About

Comment: I said in my question that I went to the about page.  I also indicated what the about page said.